# AngularJS $window.open throws "Cannot read property 'arguments' of null"

Tags: angularjs, window

I'm creating a simple web page where i display a button which execute this code

```
$window.open(link, "_self");
```

The link variable is a simple telegram link for a channel, but this is not the problem, the problem, as the question say itself, is about arguments variable in $window.open.

This in my opinion is strange because when i logged in the console $window.open function, i received this output:

```
function pbWindowOpen() {
    lastBlockCaller = {
      caller: arguments.callee.caller,
      args: arguments.callee.caller.arguments
    };

    try {
return newWindowOpenFn.apply(this, argument…
```

At this point, should not i see an argument variable inside this function? How could i solve this problem?
Passing some arguments could resolve my problem? If yes, there's an answer about why i'm having arguments null?

I've also tried with window.open but nothing changes, always the same problem

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't happen if you are running your code in a browser (in other env you may have some initialized variable `window` representing something else), $window is a wrapper in top of `var currWindow = $window.self || $window.window` and then do a perform of callong `open(...)` function. Hence, you neither using the native javascript code badly in a angular context, and again that would be easily mock-ableif we mock $window and create a property call `self` or `window` inside it. So it will work in the application, and will also be testable.